# Set the product price in iOS app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an app with **in-app purchase features**, in this app users should make a payment for each of the products (Non-Consumable).

Should I specify the price of the products beforehand in the itunes connect or can I dynamically set/override the product's price using a webservice?

Regards

Comment: The price can only be set in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't allowed to set price out side of iTunes. Here are the link that help you to change price tier at any time once your application become live.

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH33-SW1)

[image]